# android UI layout incorrect

Tags: android, layout, view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/general_detail" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- 标题栏 -->
        <include layout="@layout/general_menu_title_bar"/>     

        <!-- 地图 -->
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fast_map_w"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fast_map_h"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_ic_fast_food_map"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fast_map_m_r"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/map"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- 分类 -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fast_sort_layout_h"
        android:background="#DDD"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- 地区 -->
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fast_sort_layout_h"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_pretakout"
            android:id="@+id/region_layout">
             <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fast_sort_text"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="地区"
                android:id="@+id/region"/>
             <ImageView 
                 android:layout_width="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_size"
                 android:layout_height="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_size"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_m_t"
                 android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_m_r"
                 android:src="@drawable/selector_ic_trangle"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- 类型 -->
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fast_sort_layout_h"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_pretakout"
            android:id="@+id/category_layout">
             <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fast_sort_text"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="类型"
                android:id="@+id/category"/>

             <ImageView 
                 android:layout_width="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_size"
                 android:layout_height="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_size"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_m_t"
                 android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_m_r"
                 android:src="@drawable/selector_ic_trangle"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- 列表 -->
    <com.hy.liang.crazydirection.view.RefreshListView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/general_detail"
          android:dividerHeight="0dp"
          android:divider="@color/general_detail"
          android:fadingEdge="none"
          android:id="@+id/listview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Theses code running on most devices,the result is correct:
[image]

But running on GALAXY Note I9220,there is a problem that the rectangle image align the bottom that is not i want!
 [image]
Is there anyone can help me to fix this?
Many thanks!

Comment: what is the difference between two image? dont find anything

Comment: The rectangle image align the bottom that is not i expext!

Comment: the tab bar image? or other . can you please edit your question and show the difference?

Comment: Can you see that? Many thanks! and ...Sorry about my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just the sample only for the issue layout:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:background="#DDD"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/note_text_disabled" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_first"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="标题栏"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />
        </RelativeLayout>

         <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/note_text_disabled" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_first"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="标题栏"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

change xml as per your need hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_m_r"` from your triangle image view.

**Edited :**

Try changing :

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_size"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_m_t"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_m_r"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_ic_trangle"/>
```

To :

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_size"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/region"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/region"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_m_t"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fast_sort_ant_m_r"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_ic_trangle"/>
```

Remember to change @id/region to category if necessary

Comment: @SprinklerNotSang Hi, after a further look into your codes, I suppose 地区 should always be on left while 类型 should be on your right, how is the first image retrieved? Also, I couldn't find anywhere you generated the middle separator line, is that coming from `selector_pretakout`? If yes could you please post the code or image for this drawable object?

Comment: yes,the middle separator line is coming from selector_pretakout

Comment: @SprinklerNotSang If you still haven't solve this problem you could give my answer a try, I've edited it...

Comment: Know is fast_sort_ant_m_r defined? Has it device dependent or independent dimensions?

Comment: isn't that what you defined in this question? I'm just copying it over, the main edit is change layout_alignParentTop to layout_alignBottom, and layout_alignParentRight to layout_alignRight